# Calculate the name of a previous variable for use

Tags: jquery, variables

I need a way of finding the name of a variable loaded in a document.ready() function earlier. The name of the variable is tied up inside the id of the element that needs to call it again.

Say the variable was `var myScrollscroll5`, the id of the element that needs to call the variable again will be `scroll5`. Thus I hoped this would work.

```
'myScroll' + $('.dircore').attr('id').refresh();
```

We cannot just call the variable because the name is unknown and can only be found in the id of the element .dircore.

Oddly enough this worked in firefox only even though firebug said it was an error. Doesn't work in other browsers though.

Comment: You just need the name of the var or you also need to access the value of that var?

Answer (score 0):

You need `eval` here:

```
var sVarName = 'myScroll' + $('.dircore').attr('id');
eval(sVarName + ".refresh();");
```

Although `eval` is considered evil, it can be useful sometimes, this looks like one of those times as you don't evaluate user input just your own internal data.

Answer (score 0):

If you had  added some code that might have been helpfull.To me it seems a global vs local scope issue .  Whatever you are doing , just define the variable in global scope first and set the value inside the function whatever method you are using to instantiate the variable value . e.g

a).    //in global scope 
      var myvariable=null;

```
 //inside function
 $(document).ready(function(){
      myvariable='set_value_here'
  })
```

Then access the variable in global or local scope.

b) other options might be  define the variable as object

```
   var myScrollscroll5={value:'value', id:'idof'}

    $('#'+myScrollscroll5.id).refresh()
```

cheers :)

Comment: sure , post some more details , that might be helpful :)

Comment: I started a new question with all the info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806322/calculating-variables-from-variables-from-ids

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the jQuery .data() function to bind the data to the element, and recall it later?

Like this:

> $(document).ready(function() { $('#scroll5').data('data', value );  });

And then:

> $('.dircore').each(function() { $(this).data('data').refresh(); });

Or something like that.  This way you're also safe from circular references and memory leaks caused by them.