# Calculating Variables from Variables from ids

Tags: jquery, function, variables, ready

The following code placed in document.ready() finds every .scrollable div and creates a variable giving each panel an id and activating a scrolling script.

```
var orderit = 0;
var scrolls = {};
$('.scrollable').each(function(){
    this.id = 'scrollp' + (++orderit);
    scrolls[ 'myScroll' + this.id ] = new iScroll( this.id, { scrollbarClass: 'myScrollbar' });
});
```

The problem is that later on I need to refresh these variables by calling the `.refresh()` method embedded in the script. To do this we need the variable name. One way to get the variable would be to calculate its setup like this.

```
$('.dircore').click(function(){
    'myScroll' + $(this).attr('id').refresh();
}
```

This works in firefox only even though firebug says it is an error, but it does not work in other browsers and is clearly not the correct way of doing this.

I hope there is enough information to work off here but essentially we need to use the id of the element we want to refresh to work out it's variable and consequently call the `.refresh()` method against its variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use the jQuery .data() function to bind the data to the element, and recall it later?  This way you're also safe from circular references and memory leaks caused by them.

Like this:

> $(document).ready(function() { $('#scroll5').data('data', value );  });

And then:

> $('.dircore').each(function() { $(this).data('data').refresh(); });

Or something like that.

Comment: IM still being told that that it is undefined when the refresh method is called

Comment: The following error is being returned by FIREBUG   ----     $("#myScroll" + refreshelement).data("data" + refreshelement) is undefined
[Break On This Error] $('#myScroll' + refreshelement).data('data' + refreshelement).refresh(); ----- I have debugged everything using alerts to compare data and it should all be working

Comment: why do you write "data"+refreshelement ?  you can use the same key "data" for each element.  It only has to be unique for the element you bind it to.   please post the current code you have for binding the data and recalling it. I'll try to correct it.

Comment: Thats it. By accident we were trying to add the data to an element that did not exist. If only i'd copied yours exactly it would have worked from the beginning.